# Can we do multiple explode statements on one line in PHP?

Tags: php, explode

Can we do multiple explode() in PHP?

For example, to do this:

```
foreach(explode(" ",$sms['sms_text']) as $no)
foreach(explode("&",$sms['sms_text']) as $no)
foreach(explode(",",$sms['sms_text']) as $no)
```

All in one explode like this:

```
foreach(explode('','&',',',$sms['sms_text']) as $no)
```

What's the best way to do this?  What I want is to split the string on multiple delimiters in one line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're looking to split the string with multiple delimiters, perhaps [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) would be appropriate.

```
$parts = preg_split( '/(\s|&|,)/', 'This and&this and,this' );
print_r( $parts );
```

Which results in:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => This 
  [1] => and 
  [2] => this 
  [3] => and 
  [4] => this 
)
```

Comment: hi thanks for code but i have \r\n\ value and space to get explode its not working  foreach(preg_split('/(\r\n\ s|&|,)/',$sms['sms_text']) as $no)

Comment: thankx bro solved  foreach(preg_split("/\r\n|(\s|&|,)/",$sms['sms_text']) as $no)

Comment: `/[\s&,]+/` would be more concise.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a great solution I found at PHP.net:

```
<?php

//$delimiters must be an array.

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$text = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
$exploded = multiexplode(array(",",".","|",":"),$text);

print_r($exploded);

//And output will be like this:
// Array
// (
//    [0] => here is a sample
//    [1] =>  this text
//    [2] =>  and this will be exploded
//    [3] =>  this also 
//    [4] =>  this one too 
//    [5] => )
// )

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
function multipleExplode($delimiters = array(), $string = ''){

    $mainDelim=$delimiters[count($delimiters)-1]; // dernier

    array_pop($delimiters);

    foreach($delimiters as $delimiter){

        $string= str_replace($delimiter, $mainDelim, $string);

    }

    $result= explode($mainDelim, $string);
    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`preg_split()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to stplit a string using a regular expression, like so:

```
$text = preg_split('/( |,|&)/', $text);
```

Comment: Simplified pattern: `/[ ,&]/`.  No capture group is needed and a characters class is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php), eg

```
$delimiter = ' &,';
$token = strtok($sms['sms_text'], $delimiter);

while ($token !== false) {
    echo $token . "\n";
    $token = strtok($delimiter);
}
```

Comment: Of aaaaaaaaaaaall the duplicates for this task, this is the first time that someone actually included an implementation of `strtok()` instead of just plonking a link to the PHP docs.  Good on ya.  (...but the OP does ask for a one-liner)